# Should I recompile PHP after a system update?

Tags: php, linux, compilation, shared-libraries, centos7

I've compiled PHP a while ago with the following options :

```
mkdir -p /local/php/php-7.4.7
wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-7.4.7.tar.gz
tar -zxf php-7.4.7.tar.gz -C /local/builds
cd /local/builds/php-7.4.7
./configure \
--prefix=/local/php/php-7.4.7 \
--with-config-file-path=/local/php/php-7.4.7 \
--disable-all \
--enable-static \
--enable-fpm \
--with-fpm-user=php-fpm \
--with-fpm-group=php-fpm \
--with-fpm-systemd \
--disable-ipv6 \
--enable-cli \
--with-zlib \
--with-bz2 \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-ctype \
--with-curl \
--enable-gd \
--enable-intl \
--with-ldap \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-pdo \
--with-pdo-mysql \
--enable-shared=pdo-mysql \
--enable-phar \
--with-libxml \
--with-iconv \
--enable-dom \
--enable-filter \
--enable-tokenizer \
--enable-json \
--enable-session \
--enable-xml \
--enable-xmlreader \
--enable-xmlwriter \
--enable-opcache \
--enable-fileinfo \
--enable-simplexml \
--enable-soap \
--with-zip \
--with-pear \
--with-openssl \
--with-libdir=lib64 \
--with-mysqli \
&& make -j && make install
```

Now, I want to make a "yum update" from my server. But I wonder if I should re-compile PHP ?

I don't master this level of detail of compilation.

Here are the packages that have to be updated :

```
Installation :
 kernel                  
Mise à jour :
 bind-export-libs        
 bind-libs               
 bind-libs-lite          
 bind-license            
 bind-utils              
 centos-release          
 device-mapper           
 device-mapper-event     
 device-mapper-event-libs
 device-mapper-libs      
 kernel-headers          
 kernel-tools            
 kernel-tools-libs       
 lvm2                    
 lvm2-libs               
 microcode_ctl           
 msodbcsql17             
 openssl                 
 openssl-devel           
 openssl-libs            
 python-perf             
 sudo                    
 tzdata                  
 vim-common              
 vim-enhanced            
 vim-filesystem          
 vim-minimal             
 webmin                  
Suppression :
 kernel
```

So should I update ?

Hmmm, it seems that SO doesn't let me post because I have to add more details. I think it's due to the ratio "code/text". So, I hope this line will suffice to accecpt my question.

Comment: If you didn't use yum to install PHP, but compiled it yourself, yum update should leave your PHP alone. If you have other yum packages that depend on a particular version of PHP, you may have some housekeeping to do.

Comment: @MarkusAO, my question is about the library dependencies. If the library are updated, I'm afraid about side-effects on my php binary. On a production server, I don't want to re-compile PHP, neither have side-effects after an update.

Comment: Well, does your self-compiled PHP build have any dependencies (whether among what's listed on your yum, or otherwise)? If so, what? And do you have other stuff installed that requires a particular specific PHP version? If not, then you're fine. FYI you can get [PHP 7.4 with yum via REMI/EPEL](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2019/12/03/Install-PHP-7.4-on-CentOS-RHEL-or-Fedora) and get your software updated without having to manually curate possible dependencies and their specific versions.

Comment: Current PHP from REMI is `php74-php-7.4.14-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm`, just updated my Centos 7 box. Never had any problems with software clashes. For your production server, seriously just yum your PHP, and do test builds on your dev server. I don't really see a valid reason to build yourself if an established repo has up-to-date versions available. You definitely *do* want/need to run regular yum updates to keep all your software up to date.

Comment: @MarkusAO, I well know REMI repository. But, a pre-compiled binary PHP IS NOT what I need. I have multiple PHP-FPM versions running on the same server and each version has differents needs. My question is not whether I can do otherwise. My question is whether updating the different libraries involves re-compiling PHP.

Comment: If you compile PHP, you will obviously need to mind whatever dependencies your chosen extensions require (such as: bzip2-devel, libcurl-devel, libmcrypt-devel, libxml2-devel, and **openssl-devel** seen in your update list). To the best of my understanding, once the thing is compiled, updates to your dependencies should have no impact on what has been *compiled* (hence the term). In general that is, not specific to PHP. Only updated dependencies called at runtime might be consequential. You would only want/need to recompile if a dependency you compiled in had a noteworthy defect/vulnerability.